# Select Dynamic tag from xml through XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

In `'Root/Message/IM/IFList/IFMS'` this xpath, I can have one xml tag at a time out of four based on condition below-

```
SEFlag if Quantity = U
SIFlag  if Quantity = S
SBFlag  if Quantity = P
SLFlag if Quantity = L

eg- when Quantity is U then 
Root/Message/IM/IFList/IFMS/SEFlag and input xml would be 
<Root>
    <Message>
        <IM>
            <IFList>
                <IFMS>
                  <SEFlag></SEFlag>
                </IFMS>
            </IFList>
        </IM>
    </Message>
    </Root>
when Quantity is S then
Root/Message/IM/IFList/IFMS/SIFlag
<Root>
    <Message>
        <IM>
            <IFList>
                <IFMS>
                  <SIFlag></SIFlag>
                </IFMS>
            </IFList>
        </IM>
    </Message>
    </Root>
```

How can we select value from this tag while translation in xslt.
Note - I am using XSLT 1.0.
Thanks-

Comment: What is the expected result of the transformation?

Comment: It's interesting how we differently interpreted this question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use different approaches:

1. Use an `xsl:choose` to select the value (adjust the path of 'Quantity'):

   ```
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="Quantity='U'">
       <xsl:value-of select="SEFlag" />
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="Quantity='S'">
       <xsl:value-of select="SIFlag" />
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="Quantity='P'">
       <xsl:value-of select="SBFlag" />
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="Quantity='L'">
       <xsl:value-of select="SLFlag" />
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:message terminate="yes">ERROR: Unknown quantity!!!</xsl:message>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
   ```

   The last part stops the translation if none of the coded values is present.
2. You can use a more general approach that selects the element based on a distintive characteristic:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="Root/Message/IM/IFList/IFMS/*[contains(local-name(),'Flag')][1]" />
   ```

   This expression selects the value of the first element whose local-name contains the string `Flag`.

Which one better fits your need depends on your personal scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:variable name="flag" select="name(Message/IM/IFList/IFMS/*)" />
    <Quantity>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$flag='SEFlag'">U</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$flag='SIFlag'">S</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$flag='SBFlag'">P</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$flag='SLFlag'">L</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>?</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Quantity>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```